# Database cannot open because VBA project cannot be read in MSAccess2010 file

Tags: vba, deployment, ms-access-2010

An amateur programmer has made a nice little program that works through VBA on top of a MS-Access2010 database. We are asked to make an installer for this database+VBA project. The code runs fine on any computer with Office installed, but on computers without Office we get the error above. On computers without office we install the MS-Access2010 Runtime, which is free, in order to be able to open the .accde file at all. But this does not prevent the VBA error.

I did some research on the issue but did not find anything related to this specific scenario. How can this be troubleshooted?

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking for a difference solution than installing MS-Access2010 Runtime? From your question it sounds like this solves your problem (?). VBA isn't really good for "installing" - you could make it into an addin, which I suspect is what you are hoping to do?

Comment: @enderland Sorry, for the confusion. Obviously, some kind of Office installation needs to be present in order to be able to open the .accde file. Installing the MS Access2010 runtime accomplishes this. But then we we run into the VBA problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a version mismatch between the .accde file (sp1) and the installed ms access 2010 runtime (original) After upgrading the runtime to sp1 all was fine.